# Joint pdf of N > 1 i.i.d. random variables isotropic if and only if they are centered gaussian?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, symmetry

> Are centered Gaussian densities given by
>   $$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/(2 \sigma^2)}$$
>   the unique densities such that the joint pdf of $N > 1$ independent and identically distributed random variables
>   with density $f_X$ is isotropic, that is, rotation invariant?

Thus, one asks that, for some valid function $h$, $$\prod_{i=1}^Nf_{X}(x_i) = h(R),\qquad R = \sqrt{x_1^2+...+x_N^2}$$
This question came up in a discussion and I found it very interesting. I have attempted to solve it as follows.

Note first that $f_X$ must be symmetric, otherwise a rotation mapping $x_i$ to $-x_i$ would violate the symmetry.
Therefore, without loss of generality, we may assume that 
$$f_X(x) = c e^{-g(x^2)}$$
for some function $g$ such that $g(0)=0$ and some normalizing constant $c$. Then we need the joint pdf to satisfy 
$$f_X(x_1)\cdots f_X(x_N) = C e^{-h(R^2)}$$
for some function $h$ and some constant $C$, such that, still without loss of generality, $h(0)=0$. From this we get
$$\sum_{i=1}^N{g(x_i^2)}=h\left(\sum_{i=1}^N{x_i^2}\right)$$
Considering $x_i=0$ for $i \neq 1$, one gets
$$g(x_1^2) + (N-1) g(0) = h(x_1^2)$$
$$\therefore g(x) = h(x), \forall x > 0$$
Considering instead $x_i=0$ for $i \notin \{1,2\}$ and assuming $N > 1$, one gets
$$g(x_1^2)+g(x_2^2) = h(x_1^2+x_2^2)$$
$$g(x)+g(y) = g(x+y), \forall x,y > 0$$
$$\therefore g(x) = \lambda x, \forall x > 0$$
Thus, substituting $g$ back into $f_X$ implies that the distribution is centered Gaussian:
$$f_X(x) = c e^{-\lambda x^2}$$
Now, the observation that centered Gaussian distributions are indeed isotropic completes the proof.

---

Is the proof sound? I'm looking forward to correcting any mistakes it may have. I also welcome your own proof, or a link to a proof. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You missed a factor $\frac 12$ in the exponent of the expression for the density function.

Comment: @JohnBentin Corrected thanks

Comment: Some PDFs are not $f_X(x) = k_1 e^{-g(|x|)}$.

Comment: @Did But if they are not $f_X(x)= k_1 e^{-g(|x|)}$ they are asymmetrical around the origin and thus clearly non isotropic (in particular under 180 degree rotations such that ${x_i}$ is mapped into ${-x_i}$ the functions don't match)

Comment: Right. Maybe add the argument to the post.

Comment: @Did Ah ok. I'm thinking that absolute value might be unnecessary since it doesn't make the following argument any easier. Indeed if I drop it I can highlight that the Taylor series of $g$ has only even terms. Thanks.

Comment: Yes but using the symmetry one gets $f_X(x)\propto\exp(g(x^2))$ hence $\sum g(x_i^2)=h\left(\sum x_i^2\right)+C$ and it seems one can conclude from there with no Taylor series.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. For $N=2$ for example, how does $g(x_1^2)+g(x_2^2)=h(x_1^2+x_2^2)$ imply $g(x)∝x$? It seems to follow from linear algebra that $g$ and $h$ must both be linear but I can't quite pinpoint how.

Comment: @Did Ah I see it now, thanks. I remade the proof. Looks good?

Comment: Quite good, yes. The step [$g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$ for every positive $x$ and $y$] $\implies$ [$g$ linear], might be made somewhat more precise.

Comment: @Did I think I've found an argument, but it's quite nasty :) I can assume $g(1)=k$, then $2 g(1/2) = g(1)$, and so on, which seems to imply that $g(\frac{a}{2^b})= \lambda_1 \frac{a}{2^b}, \forall a,b \in \mathbb{N}$, which doesn't cover all reals, right?  There's an observation I didn't make that $g$ must be non-decreasing that should complete the gap. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Indeed this is the classical way to prove that [additive implies linear] but yes, one further argument is needed, which is usually either continuity or monotonicity. Here I see no reason why $g$ should be non-decreasing.

Comment: @Did The idea is fuzzy, but I was thinking that if $f_X(x)$ has a "bump" (increases for $x>0$), then $f_{{X_1}{X_2}}$ gets some 'square strips' that make it non-isotropic. And then noting $f_X$ increases if and only if $g$ decreases. I'm not sure I could state this precisely.

Comment: @Did I thought about it and I think I'm almost there (I'd like to prove without assuming $f_X$ is continuous): if we assume that the joint distribution is indeed rotation invariant, then we could apply a small irrational rotation along some axis mapping $x$ into $\alpha x$ and the i.i.d. decomposition $f_X'$ must stay the same. For example, $f_{{X_1}{X_2}}(x,0) = c^2 \exp{(-x^2 \lambda_1)}, \forall x \in S_1 = f_{{X_1}{X_2}}(x cos(\theta),x sin(\theta) ) = c^2 \exp{(-x^2 (\lambda_{cos(\theta)} cos^2(\theta) + \lambda_{sin(\theta)} sin^2(\theta) ) )}$ (Continues)

Comment: (Continuing) Which gives for example $\lambda_{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{1}{4} + \lambda_{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}} \frac{3}{4} = \lambda_1$. But $\lambda_{\frac{1}{2}}=\lambda_1$, so we get $\lambda_{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}} = \lambda_1$. Do you think this could work, forcing $\lambda_{\alpha} = \lambda_1, \forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ ?